# Webpack minified distribution file issue

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

First of all i gotta say that i am a webpack newcomer and i have been working with this awesome tool for like 2 weeks and i've managed to achieve everything i needed except for this.

Here's the deal: At my company we are trying to abstract a common set of inputs, components and common css to a module hosted on a separate repository so it can serve as a vendor within our other modules, it's called **Mandioca**. All of our application are developed using Angularjs framework, so it's an angular module.

I am bundling everything together on a minified file that contains all `.js` files and outputting it on a folder called `dist`. No big deal.

The issue happens when i try to import mandioca within any other modules. I am getting this exception: `TypeError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`

I think it's a problem within the minified file because when i stop importing Mandioca on the module's dependencies the error goes away:

```
// Exception :(
angular.module('app', [
    'Mandioca',
    // (...other dependencies)
]);

// Everything OK
angular.module('app', [
    // (...other dependencies)
]);
```

I dived at webpack config docs and angular + webpack cookbook and came across some interesting stuff that unfortunately did not solved my problem:

Specifying `externals`:

```
externals: {
  angular: 'angular',
}
```

Specifying `output` libraryTarget options:

```
config.output = {
  path: path.join(__dirname, distFolder),
  filename: (isBuild ? minJs : '[name].bundle.js'),
  libraryTarget: 'umd' // <--- here's the tweak
};
```

Some other things to have in mind:

- The Mandioca module runs dev task normally, so does development with minified files with no crash.
- All the other modules runs dev tasks normally
- Im using webpack-dev-server for those tasks.

Mandioca's Webpack file:

```js
// webpack stuff
import webpack from 'webpack';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import WebpackNotifierPlugin from 'webpack-notifier';
// import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';

// postcss
import rucksack from 'rucksack-css';
import cssnano from 'cssnano';
import nested from 'postcss-nested';
import mixins from 'postcss-mixins';
import simpleVars from 'postcss-simple-vars';
import cssnext from 'postcss-cssnext';
import postcssImport from 'postcss-import';

import vendors from './vendors.json';
import path from 'path';

export default function makeWebpackConfig(options) {
  const vendorsDir = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules');
  const excludeVendors = /node_modules/;
  const distFolder = 'dist';
  const minJs = 'mandioca.min.js';
  const minCss = 'mandioca.min.css';
  const devEntry = './app/app.dev.js';
  const distEntry = './app/app.dist.js';
  const isTest = !!options.TEST;
  const isBuild = !!options.BUILD;
  const isDev = !isBuild && !!options.DEV;
  const isDevProd = isBuild && !!options.DEV;

  const getCssLoader = (build) => {
    let baseStr = 'css?sourceMap!postcss';

    return build ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', baseStr) : 'style!' + baseStr;
  };

  const esLintPreLoader = {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'eslint',
    exclude: excludeVendors
  };

  const jsLoader = {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['ng-annotate', 'babel'],
    exclude: excludeVendors
  };

  const cssLoader = {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: getCssLoader(isBuild),
    exclude: excludeVendors
  };

  const vendorsCssLoader = {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style!css?sourceMap',
    include: excludeVendors
  };

  const filesLoader = {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
    loader: 'file',
    exclude: excludeVendors
  };

  const htmlLoader = {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loaders: ['ngtemplate', 'html'],
    exclude: excludeVendors
  };

  const config = {
    resolve: {
      alias: {}
    },
    plugins: [],
    entry: {
      app: ((isBuild && !isDevProd) ? distEntry : devEntry),
      vendor: []
    },
    module: {},
    externals: {
      angular: 'angular',
    }
  };

  config.output = {
    path: path.join(__dirname, distFolder),
    filename: (isBuild ? minJs : '[name].bundle.js'),
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  };

  if (!isBuild && (isDev || isDevProd)) {
    config.module.noParse = [];
    vendors.forEach((vendor) => {
      let vendorPath = path.resolve(vendorsDir, vendor);
      // config.module.noParse.push(vendorPath);
      config.entry.vendor.push(vendorPath);
      config.resolve.alias[vendor.split(path.sep)[0]] = vendorPath;
    });
  }

  if (!isTest) {
    // Reference: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    // Render index.html
    config.plugins.push(
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './index.html',
        inject: true,
        production: isBuild,
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        moment: 'moment',
        R: 'ramda',
        CPF: 'cpf_cnpj'
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        filename: (isBuild && !isDevProd) ? minJs : '[name].bundle.js',
      }),
      // Reference: https://github.com/Turbo87/webpack-notifier
      // Pops a notification on error
      new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false }})
    );
  }

  config.postcss = function(webp) {
    let cssnanoOpt = {
      discardUnused: false,
      zindex: false
    };
    let rucksackOpt = { autoprefixer: true };

    let devPlugins = [
      postcssImport({ addDependencyTo: webp }),
      mixins,
      nested,
      simpleVars,
      rucksack(rucksackOpt),
      cssnext
    ];
    let prodPlugins = [cssnano(cssnanoOpt)];

    let plugins;
    if (isBuild) {
      plugins = devPlugins;
    } else {
      plugins = devPlugins.concat(prodPlugins);
    }

    return plugins;
  };

  config.module.preLoaders = [esLintPreLoader];
  config.module.loaders = [jsLoader, cssLoader, htmlLoader, filesLoader];

  if (isBuild || isDevProd) {
    config.plugins.push(new ExtractTextPlugin(minCss));
  }

  if (isDevProd || isDev) {
    config.module.loaders.push(vendorsCssLoader);
  }

  return config;
}
```

I dont know, but maybe that's not webpack's responsibility. Anyway any information that could lead me out of this blocker i would be more than glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a quick look at your webpack config I found an error on the CommonsChunks plugin. You're naming the generated CommonsChunks file with the same name as your output entry file. So the output file (with your code) is being replaced by the CommonsChunks file.

If you're making a library to be distributed, you won't need a vendor file, so I would try to remove the CommonsChunk plugin and see if it works.

Comment: That's it! Thanks dude!